# Groovy: parse string with special symbols

Tags: java, xml, groovy, xml-parsing, escaping

I have this description that I get from user:
`sample description with special symbols >`.

I want to parse this into a valid XML format string to pass it in my REST call. Currently, if I pass this as is, my third party implementation fires an exception, saying **"it cannot handle any special symbols"**

I have tried XMLParser, XmlSlurper but all fire exception as

> [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>   Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: Appreciate if you can up vote for the helpful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be escaped if you are sending it inside xml.

**Approach 1:**

change from `>` to `&gt;` in the value.

**Approach 2:**
Put the string inside `CDATA` as shown below.

```
<![CDATA[sample description with special symbols >]]>
```